# C# Hashtable of FileSystemWatchers

Tags: c#, static, directory, hashtable, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to create a hashtable of filesystem watchers. This is to keep a running record of active filesystemwatchers with the directories they are watching as keys. Then via a form the user can add and delete folders to watch, which are visible in a listview or something.

My main problem is how to "keep" the hash table between methods and classes. I'm a bit of a novice to C# and it doesn't seem to work the way I'm used to in VB.NET.

So I have (stripped down to simplify):

```
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public static Hashtable globalHashTable;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileSystemWatcher watcher1 = new FileSystemWatcher(@"C:\");
            globalHashTable.Add(@"C:\",watcher1);
        }
    }
}
```

So that a filesystemwatcher is added to the hashtable. However since the globalhashtable is static (?) this won't work. Making it non static means I have to create an instance of it when the buttton is pressed, so I have a new one each time as it's not "kept". My problem is how to keep a table in memory between methods and classes.

I'm fairly sure I've majorly misunderstood something as I'm new to all of this. Also I doubt this is even a half decent way to do this, if anyone has a better way, then please go ahead!

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: *"Making it non static means I have to create an instance of it when the buttton is pressed"*, no, it just means you have to make an instance of it once, like in your constructor. I'm not sure what you mean "between classes" though, where are you sharing this? You would just need to make a public-ly accessible property that returns the instance you created for it to be available between other active class objects. Also, you should look into a `Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher>` instead of hash table to avoid boxing.

Comment: I agree with @RonBeyer's suggestion of using a Dictionary instead of a hash table. Also beware of directories that have a ton of subdirectories and files. .NET Filewatchers don't always play nice.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Ron Beyer's suggestion you can do something like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher> _fileSystemWatcherMap;

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _fileSystemWatcherMap = new Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher>();
}

public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pathToWatch = @"C:\"; // Must be a different path each time otherwise will throw
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(pathToWatch);
    _fileSystemWatcherMap.Add(pathToWatch, watcher);
}
```

This way all methods in the MainForm can access the file watchers.

If you need to share this among forms that are created from MainForm you can simply pass this data before showing the dialog.

If the other form is created in a different way the you can create a static class like this:

```
public static class FileWatcherMap
{
    private static Dictionary<string, FileSystemWatcher> _fileSystemWatcherMap = new Dictionary<string,FileSystemWatcher>();

    public static void AddWatcher(string path, FileSystemWatcher fsw)
    {
        _fileSystemWatcherMap.Add(path, fsw);
    }

    public static void RemoveWatcher(string path)
    {
        _fileSystemWatcherMap.Remove(path);
    }
}
```

then in the click handler you add the watcher to this list:

```
public void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pathToWatch = @"C:\"; // Must be a different path each time otherwise will throw
    var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(pathToWatch);
    FileWatcherMap.AddWatcher(pathToWatch, watcher);
}
```

Now FileWatcherMap class would be accessible from any other form

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I'lll have a go and let you know. Thankyou for explaining as I knew what I had must have made no sense...